# Issue with sidecar proxy logs when using TLS in Passthrough mode

Tags: ssl, logging, https, istio-sidecar

I've set up a simple testing service using TLS in PASSTHROUGH mode. I can access the service successfully using HTTPS every time I make a request. However when looking at the sidecar proxy logs, the request are only logged from time to time. And only very few of them are actually logged. Sometime the log appears (when it appears) a minute after the request. It's very weird and I am not talking about load testing, just few request from the browser.

Please note that when using the service in HTTP (port 80), the logs work perfectly.

I first thought that there was something wrong with my deployment so I tried a deployment equivalent,  the nginx example found [here](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/en/asm/user-guide/use-an-ingress-gateway-to-enable-tls-pass-through) and I observe the exact same behavior that is, only very few requests are logged in the Envoy proxy in a random way.

In my case the last version of Istio (installed using istioctl) is deployed on an EKS cluster.
My plan is to go to production at some point with Istio but I am blocked with this basic setup. I've spent hours looking for some hint on forums etc... but no luck.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!